# Triggered event on b-button doesn't show on wrapper.emitted()

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I'm new to testing vue components and right now I'm trying to test that clicking a b-button component trigger an event and calls a method.

The test seems to fail because the 'click' event doesn't get triggered.

Also note that i'm using Nuxt.js

The component containing b-button is the following:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-input name="username" type="text" v-model="username"></b-form-input>
    <b-form-input name="password" type="password" v-model="password"></b-form-input>
    <b-button @click="login">Login</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      dispatchLogin: "auth/login"
    }),
    login: () => {
      const response = this.dispatchLogin(this.username, this.password);
      response.then(this.$router.push("/dashboard"));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And the test is written like that:

```
    test('call login when Login button gets clicked', async () => {

        expect.assertions(2);

        moxios.stubRequest('/api/auth/login', {
            response: 200
        });

        const store = new Vuex.Store(storeConfig);
        const mocks = {
            login: jest.fn()
        }
        const wrapper = shallowMount(login, { localVue, store, mocks });
        debugger;
        // Note that b-button is stubbed as <button></button>
        wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');  

        await flushPromises()

        expect(wrapper.emitted('click')).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(auth.actions.login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

The problem is that I can't find any click event in wrapper.emitted().

Comment: That's because no `click` is emitted. `wrapper.find('button').trigger('click');` invokes the click event on the button. The component being tested does not emit any events from it's code

Comment: `b-button` is a functional component (no `this` context), and emits native events. So `@click` is actually listening for native events in this case. You would need to set up a `const spy = jest.fn()` to listen for clicks, and bind it to the button when you mount it.